# How to embed subtitles .srt file into video stream using VLC

Tags: video-processing, vlc

I have an .mp4 and an .srt and I'd like to cast them to a chromecast. apparently chromecast does not support subtitles tracks, so I need to encode the .srt file into the video.

Using VLC, I tried to use "Convert / Save" with Overlay Subtitles checkbox - that created a movie without subtitles.

I tried to use "Stream" to file with the exact transcoding profile - that created a file without audio or video tracks at all(!!!).

what am I missing?

Comment: I eventually used HandBrake to do the job. Was much slower, but worked. I wonder if this is at all possible with VLC.

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem, but I can suggest [Gnomecast](https://github.com/keredson/gnomecast) or [Videostream](https://getvideostream.com/)  for casting video with subtitles